# What is the Aggregate root in this case

Tags: domain-driven-design, entities, aggregateroot

I have these entities

- User
- Task - every task must have a user assigned
- Project - a task can be assigned to a project but it's not necessary, user must be assigned as a project creator
- TaskStatus - every task must have a status assigned

and I designed the aggregate roots as follows

Aggregate roots

- User with entities:Task, Task status
- Project

Am I going in right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, sounds quite right. This is my improvisation in c#:

```
//aggregate root
public class User{/*first name, last name, contacts, etc.*/}

//aggregate root
public class Project{
  public IList Tasks{get; private set;}
  public User CreatedBy{get; private set;}
  public Project(User createdBy){
    CreatedBy=createdBy;
  }
  public RegisterTask(string taskDescription, User assignedTo){
    Tasks.Add(new Task(taskDescription, assignedTo));
  }
  public StartWorkOn(Task task){
    if(!Tasks.Contains(task))
      throw new Exception("Task is not registered");
    task.StartWork();
  }
}

//entity
public class Task{
  public User AssignedTo{get;private set;}
  public string Description{get; private set;}
  public TaskStatus Status{get; private set;}
  internal Task(string description, User assignedTo){
    AssignedTo=assignedTo;
    Description=description;
    Status=TaskStatus.Pending;
  }
  internal void StartWork(){
    if(Status!=TaskStatus.Pending)
      throw new Exception("Can't start what's ongoing");
    Status=TaskStatus.InProgress;
  }
  internal void Finish(){
    if(Status!=TaskStatus.InProgress)
      throw new Exception("Can't finish what has not started");
    Status=TaskStatus.Finished;
  }      
}

//value object
public enum TaskStatus{ Pending, InProgress, Finished }

var me=new User();
_users.Save(me);

var you=new User();
_users.Save(you);

var project=new Project(me);
project.RegisterTask("Have a nice day!", you);
project.StartWorkOn(project.Tasks.First());
_projects.Save(project);
```

Keep in mind - that's just a sketch. Don't take it too seriously.

Comment: A task doesn't need to be assigned to a project,but it must be created by a user. Therefore I chose User to be a AR for the task entity, because a task can't exist without an user but it can exist without a project. Am I right here ?

Comment: Sounds reasonable so far. But then again - there arises other questions to brainstorm about. E.g. likely - project has members and, if task is project specific, it should be registrable only if member is assigned to project.

Comment: I thought one AR can reference another one ? It could be an invariant of the project. Project can be created only if User is assigned.

Comment: Yes, AR can be referenced from another one.